# Как вывести позицию наибольшего элемента в двумерном массиве?

Tags: java, массивы, циклы, переменные, область-видимости

Есть программа, которая предлагает пользователю ввести двумерный массив и отображает его наибольший элемент. Подскажите, как вывести его позицию?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int row, column;
        
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Получение от пользователя количество строк и столбцов.
        System.out.print("Введите кол-во строк и столбцов массива: ");
        row = input.nextInt();
        column = input.nextInt();

        //Инициализая двумерного массива пользователем.
        int[][] array = getArray(row, column);

        
         locateLargest(array);

        System.out.print("Наибольшее значение массива равно " + locateLargest(array));
    }

        //Метод, который заполняет двумерный массив пользователем
        public static int[][] getArray(int row, int column) {
            int[][] array1 = new int[row][column];
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            for (int r = 0; r < array1.length; r++) {
                System.out.println("Введите " + column + " значений,через пробел, заполнив строку: ");
                for (int c = 0; c < array1[r].length; c++) {
                    array1[r][c] = input.nextInt();
                }
            }
            return array1;
        }

        //Метод, который отображает наибольший элемент в массиве
        //и должен опеределять его позицию.
        public static int locateLargest(int[][] a) {
            int rowIndex = 0;
            int columnIndex = 0;
            int max = a[rowIndex][columnIndex];
            for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++) {
                    if (a[i][j] > max)
                        max = a[i][j];
                    rowIndex = i;
                    columnIndex = j;
                }
            }
            return max;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Отформатируйте вопрос и перенесите заголовок в тело.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Если равных элементов матрицы несколько, то как вывести первый элемент? Java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1474104/)

Answer (score 0):

1. В представленном коде при поиске *позиции* максимума неправильно присваиваются значения индексов `rowIndex`, `columnIndex`, так как оператор `if` записан без скобок `{}`.
   То есть, значения `rowIndex`, `columnIndex` будут обновляться на каждой итерации независимо от обнаружения максимума.
2. Чтобы вывести *позицию* максимума следует либо сделать это в методе `locateLargest` *перед* возвращением максимума (в простейшем случае), либо добавить некий класс-обёртку `MaxInfo`, хранящий максимум и пару индексов максимума, и вернуть экземпляр такого класса.

Также следует учесть, что в *общем случае* максимум не всегда может найден.

```java
static class MaxInfo {
    int max, row, col;
    
    public MaxInfo(int val, int row, int col) {
        this.setMax(val, row, col);
    }
    
    public final void setMax(int val, int row, int col) {
        this.max = val;
        this.row = row;
        this.col = col;
    }
    
    @Override 
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Максимальное значение: %d, строка: %d, столбец: %d", max, row, col);
    }
}

public static MaxInfo findMax(int[][] arr) {
    MaxInfo max = null;
    
    if (null != arr && arr.length > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (max == null && arr[i] != null && arr[i].length > 0) {
                max = new MaxInfo(arr[i][0], i, 0);
            }
            for (int j = 0; arr[i] != null && j < arr[i].length; j++) {
                if (max.max < arr[i][j]) {
                    max.setMax(arr[i][j], i, j);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    return max;
}
```

Тест:

```java
int[][] arr = {
    null,
    {},
    {2, 4, 10, 15},
    {1, 8, 20},
    {7, 3}
};

System.out.println(findMax(arr));
```

Результат:

```
Максимальное значение: 20, строка: 3, столбец: 2
```